# unable to test the function in angularjs controller in switch case

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test below function. I am using jasmine for testing the same

```
var razorPaySuccessCallback = function(payment_id) {
                            $scope.razorpayParams.razorpay_payment_id = payment_id;
                            $http( {
                                url: <url>,
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'Authorization': ''
                                },
                                transformRequest: function ( obj ) {
                                                                            }

                                },
                                data:<data>
                            } );
                        }
```

i was trying like below.

```
spyOn(this, 'razorPaySuccessCallback').and.callFake(function() {
        return {
          then: function(callback) { return callback(data); }
        };
    });
```

i am getting razorPaySuccessCallback is not exist.

Comment: Can you show us full test?

Comment: What is "this" in the context of your spyOn call?